# Reformat a string with special tokens to a list/dictionary containing its tokens as elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, string-formatting

I have a string (as an output of a model that *generates* sequences) in the format --

```
<bos> <new_gen> ent1 <gen> rel1_ent1 <gen> rel2_ent1 <new_gen> ent2 <gen> rel1_ent2 <eos>
```

Because this is a collection of elements generated as a sentence/sequence, I would like to reformat it to a list/dictionary (to evaluate the quality of responses) --

```
[ [ent1, rel1_ent1, rel2_ent1], [ent2, rel1_ent2] ] or
{ "ent1" : ["rel1_ent1", "rel2_ent1"], "ent2" : ["rel1_ent2"] }
```

So far, the way I have been looking at this is via splitting the string by `<bos>`  and/or `<eos>` special tokens -- `test_string.split("<bos>")[1].split("<eos>")[0].split("<rel>")[1:]`. But I am not sure how to handle generality if I do this across a large set of sequences with varying length (i.e. # of rel_ents associated with a given ent).

Also, I feel there might be a more optimal way to do this (without ugly splitting and looping) -- maybe regex?. Either way, I am entirely unsure and *looking for a more optimal solution*.

Added note: the special tokens `<bos>, <new_gen>, <gen>, <eos>` can be entirely removed from the generated output if that helps.

Comment: `["rel1_ent1", "rel2_ent1"]`  can you explain where the `rel2_ent1` comes from? Do you wish to alter the output or is this a typo?

Comment: rel2_ent1 is the "second" relation associated with entity 1 (fixed typo)). Similarly, rel1_ent2 is the 1st relation associated with entity 2. There can be any variable # of relations associated with any variable # of ents.

Comment: can I assume if string having `<>`  are special tokens and can be removed ?

Comment: yes @novice, any/all special tokens can be removed if that helps.

Comment: is every new entity and relation starts with `<new_gen> tag`? Do entity  and relation name can contain space ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there could be a smoother way without, as you mentioned it "*ugly splitting and looping*", but maybe `re.finditer` could be a good option here. Find each substring of interest with pattern:

```
<new_gen>\s(\w+)\s<gen>\s(\w+(?:\s<gen>\s\w+)*)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/f3bL3R/1). We then can use capture group 1 as our key values and capture group 2 as a substring we need to split again into lists:

```
import regex as re

s = '<bos> <new_gen> ent1 <gen> rel1_ent1 <gen> rel2_ent1 <new_gen> ent2 <gen> rel1_ent2 <eos>'
result = re.finditer(r'<new_gen>\s(\w+)\s<gen>\s(\w+(?:\s<gen>\s\w+)*)', s)
d = {}
for match_obj in result:
        d[match_obj.group(1)] = match_obj.group(2).split(' <gen> ')
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'ent1': ['rel1_ent1', 'rel2_ent1'], 'ent2': ['rel1_ent2']}
```

Comment: unsure why but the regex you suggested fails to capture "ent(i)" if it is composed of multiple tokens/words. For example, if ent1 was formatted as "ent 1", it'll fail.

Comment: @RahulDev it's because I used word-characters with `\w+` to capture word without whitespace. You could edit the pattern to include whitespaces, for example using a character class instead.