# Capture sequence of words separated by whitespace thru existing regex

Tags: python, regex

Following up from an earlier version of this question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73142653/reformat-a-string-with-special-tokens-to-a-list-dictionary-containing-its-tokens).

I have a string of the form --

`test = "<bos> <start> some fruits: <mid> apple, oranges <mid> also pineapple <start> some animals: <mid> dogs, cats <eos>"`

which needs to be converted to a dictionary `(<str>:[List])` of the form:

`{"some fruits:" : ["apples, oranges", "also pineapple"], "some animals:" ["dogs, cats"]}`

Everything between two `<mid>` tags is a single string, whereas multiple `<mid>` tags followed by `<start>` mean different strings.

Currently, my regex (from the post linked above) looks like this

`res = re.finditer(r'<start>\s(\w+)\s<mid>\s(\w+(?:\s<mid>\s\w+)*), test)'`

which can then be iterated over to create a dictionary --

```
test_dict = {}
for match in res:
    test_dict[match.group(1)] = match.group(2).split(' <mid> ')
```

However, I am unable to capture *multiple* words between `<start>/<mid>/<mid>` tags (i.e. separated by whitespace, comma etc).

How can this regex be formatted to capture everything between multiple `<>` tags?

Comment: why do you need `bos` and `eos` if you know the string will be representated as a dict type?

Comment: you don't, you can ignore them. I copy-pasted an example because the entire string is the output of a generated sequence and <bos> & <eos> are auto-generated (but can be safely ignored).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `re.findall`:

```
data = {}
for m in re.findall(r'(<\w+>)\s+([^<]+)', test):
    if m[0] == '<start>':
        l = data.setdefault(m[1].strip(), [])
    elif m[0] == '<mid>':
        l.append(m[1].strip())
```

Output:

```
>>> data
{'some fruits:': ['apple, oranges', 'also pineapple'],
 'some animals:': ['dogs, cats']}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a non-regex approach, you can strip out the `<bos>` and `<eos>` tags since you know that you want a `dict` object, and then use `str.split` to split on specific tags. Note that I am only using this approach as you don't have end tags to keep a track of, like `</mid>`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

test = "<bos> <start> some fruits: <mid> apple, oranges <mid> also pineapple <start> some animals: <mid> dogs, cats <eos>"

test = test[5:-5].strip()

result = defaultdict(list)

for item in test.split('<start>'):
    if not item:
        continue

    key, *vals = item.strip().split('<mid>')
    result[key].extend(val.strip() for val in vals)

print(result)
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'some fruits: ': ['apple, oranges', 'also pineapple'], 'some animals: ': ['dogs, cats']})
```

Possibly you could make do with a regex approach too, but haven't tested with one yet.